# Any way to recognize pattern(such as Char and Number) from image without labeled data?

Tags: deep-learning, pattern-recognition, unsupervised-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to build a captcha recognizer. I found CNN play very well if there are enough labeled data.

For example, I use this https://github.com/lepture/captcha to generate 4 size char+number captcha sample.
But I found it only could recognize captchas with similar style, didn't work when I gave it a different style one.

Since it is hard to mock captcha with different style every time. I wonder is there any more generic way to do this.

What I can imagine is :

1. Use some deep learning method, learn char from a large unlabeled captcha dataset.
2. For example, one pic may has 4 features, another may has 5 features, a dataset has many pics. Here, features indicate to `a-z A-Z 1-9` , the problem is get the features out and divide them into groups
3. features be divided groups it doesn't know which pic is which number
4. then human can label the **learned features/pattern** to real meaning(such as a-z A-Z 1-9)
5. then use that to build model.

I think this way is very ideal, but I have no idea how to start. I have heard deconvolution or some clustering method can generate some pattern , but I am not very familiar with these technique.

Is there any good approach or suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0):

This is should be possible, as some of the Google tools could be considered existence proofs for workable solutions. Consider, for instance, [street number recognition](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/42241.pdf).

Whether it's easy to replicate/extend such systems without their implementation details, engineering teams and hardware is another matter. In this case I think the data has been [made available](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/).